# JPA: how to map SQL Server uniqueidentifier type

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I've inherited a SQL Server database that I'm trying to map via JPA. Many of the tables have a `uniqueidentifier` column. I'm trying to map them like so:

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID")
private String id;
```

Hibernate complains with:

```
Found: uniqueidentifier, expected: varchar(255)
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918942/2102158

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The data type of the primary key property in the POJO determines the data type of its mapped DB column, which is specified by the [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) class. According to the [SQLServerDialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLServerDialect.html) provided by hibernate, it does not have any data type that maps to `uniqueidentifier`, and `String` by default maps to `varchar(255)`

I think  `guid` strategy on a `String` primary key only means that hibernate will  generate a GUID value for POJO's primary key property  and this generated  GUID value will be inserted to the `varchar(255)` column to simulate the effect of `uniqueidentifier`

You can try to override the mapping specified by the [Dialect](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) class by using the [columnDefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#columnDefinition%28%29) attribute of `@Column`

```
 @Id
 @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
 @Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID" , columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
 private String id;
```

Comment: I convinced our DBA to move to integer-based PKs, but before doing so I applied your columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier" suggestion, which solved type mismatch issue.

Comment: Worked for me also. Note that I was able to remove the "parameters" argument from @ GenericGenerator and "name" from @ Column. I didn't want to override those values =)

Comment: Warning! [GUIDGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/GUIDGenerator.html) is DEPRECATED : use [UUIDGenerator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerator.html) instead with custom [UUIDGenerationStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerationStrategy.html) implementation. Nowadays it should be `@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid2")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `uuid2`

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid2", parameters = {})
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "APPLICATION_ID" , columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier")
private String id;
```

This works for me.

Comment: Your solution contains the columnDefinition="uniqueidentifier" settings which is mentioned in the accepted answer. Does you solution work without this settings?