# With hibernate JPA and sql server how do I map uniqueidentifier?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm mapping a legacy database. The view is read-only.

```
@Column(name = "book_id", columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
public String getBookId() {
    return this.bookId;
}
```

This gives the error

```
for column book_id. Found: uniqueidentifier, expected: `uniqueidentifier`
```

This is using spring boot, JPA with sql server, driver class name com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: how to map SQL Server uniqueidentifier type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451772/jpa-how-to-map-sql-server-uniqueidentifier-type)

Comment: It uses the 'uniqueidentifier' definition. I get this back-tick enclosed response.